# Http Client using HTTP POST in Deno

Tags: http, post, httpclient, deno

I would like to write a http client in [Deno](https://deno.land/) using an *HTTP POST*. Is this possible in Deno at this time?

For reference, is an example of doing an http GET in Deno:

```
const response = await fetch("<URL>");
```

I looked at the [HTTP module](https://deno.land/std/http/) in Deno and it appears to be focused on server side only at this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do a `multipart/form-data` `POST`, form post data can be packaged using the [FormData](https://github.com/denoland/deno/blob/master/cli/js/web/form_data.ts) object. Here is a client side example for sending form data over *HTTP POST*:

```js
    // deno run --allow-net http_client_post.ts
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append("field1", "value1");
    form.append("field2", "value2");
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
        body: form 
    });
    
    console.log(response)
```

Update 2020-07-21:

As per answer from @fuglede, to send `JSON` over `HTTP` `POST`:

```js
    const response = await fetch(
      url,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ field1: "value1", field2: "value2" })
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is useful for `multipart/form-data`-encoded data, but it's worth noting that the same approach can be used to submit data of other encodings as well. For instance, to POST JSON data, you can just use a string for the `body` argument, which ends up looking something like the below:

```js
const messageContents = "Some message";
const body = JSON.stringify({ message: messageContents });
const response = await fetch(
  url,
  {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: body,
  },
);
```

Comment: Thanks. This reminds me that my method below should be explicit with the Content-Type header.